# How to recover keys

Tags: gnupg, seahorse, pgp

I recently did a fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04 on my workstation. I made a complete backup of my home directory, and have been pulling out the bits that I need. I had set up a signing key for my git commits, and failed to export it before the reinstallation. Of course, the file are still in `~/.gnupg`. I'm not exactly sure of the structure in this directory, such as where the public and private keys are, and if just moving them over is sufficient. I'm worried about doing something stupid and messing up my existing installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all copying over `~/.gnupg` to a new machine should be fine and working. See [Moving/Copying your PGP Keys](https://www.phildev.net/pgp/gpg_moving_keys.html) as reference.

Accordingly to the git documentation [Git - Signing Your Work](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Signing-Your-Work) you should be able to see your existing key via:

```
gpg --list-keys
```

Your existing key should be listed there.

If it is check git repo or global configuration if and what key is currently set:

- for "repo only" configuration (you have to be within your repo directory):

  ```
  git config user.signingkey
  ```
- global:

  ```
  git config --global user.signingkey
  ```

If key from `gpg --list-keys` command and git config match you should be fine.

If git **user.signingkey** config is empty set it with

```
git config --global user.signingkey 0A46826A
```

where "0A46826A" should be your existing key hash.